# Python lambda+exec scope error

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, scope

In the following code, the first reference to `iszero` succeeds but the second (inside the lambda) gives a `NameError: 'iszero' is not defined`.

```
myblock = """
def iszero(x):
    return x == 0

print(iszero(0)) #works

args = [0, 1, 2]

flts = list(filter(lambda f:(not iszero(f)), args)) #NameError
"""

mylocals = {}
exec(myblock, globals(), mylocals)
```

Comment: May I ask why your script uses not only `lambda`, but also `exec()` and `globals()`?

Comment: @user5090812  Are you suing `Python3`?

Comment: @gsb-eng `Python 3.4.3`

Comment: There is a 99% chance that you could accomplish your [actual goal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) more simply.

Comment: I....can actually reproduce this. `flts = lambda x: iszero(z) ; print(flts(1))` also NameErrors.

Comment: Why are you passing locals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd classify this as a Python bug (at very least a documentation bug).

You should open an issue in the [Python bug tracker...](https://bugs.python.org/)

The problem is not related to `lambda`, looks like closures created by exec when a `locals` dictionary is provided don't have the correct scope resolution.

Curiously enough PyPy has the same behavior, so **may be** this is indeed the expected result (I can't understand where it's documented, however).

## EDIT

It may seem strange but this is the expected behavior.

The reason is that when `exec` is provided both a `global` and `local` dictionary the code is executed like if it was **in the body of a class definition**.

That context is quite specific and closures created in it cannot access names defined in the scope of the class (that's why you need to use `myclass.myattribute` in methods to access class attributes - and that's a lookup that starts from global).

This strange behavior doesn't bite often because normally code at class definition scope just does simple assignments (for class-level attributes) and definitions (for methods) that doesn't try to capture those names.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood here is that, `exec(myblock)` this is always adding entities to the `locals()`. I did verified the below scenarios..

This is how python manages `locals` and `globals` when you use `exec`.

```
if (globals == Py_None) {
    globals = PyEval_GetGlobals();
    if (locals == Py_None) {
        locals = PyEval_GetLocals();
        if (locals == NULL)
            return NULL;
    }
    if (!globals || !locals) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_SystemError,
                        "globals and locals cannot be NULL");
       return NULL;
    }
}
else if (locals == Py_None)
    locals = globals;
```

As per the above logic when you do `exec(myblock, None, None)` python gets `globals()` and works equal to this expression `exec(myblock, globals(), globals())` as pert the above logic. below is the simple expression to verify whether `locals() is globals()` or not when we provide both `None`.

```
>>> exec("print(locals() is globals())", None, None)
True
```

In the same way when we provide `locals` as `None`, as per the above python logic `if (locals == Py_None) locals = globals`, both would refer the same object and that is `globals`.

```
>>> exec("print(locals() is globals())", globals(), None)
True
```

And when we pass `locals` as empty dict `{}`, as per the above logic it won't do any kind of changes to local variables.

```
>>> exec("print(locals() is globals())", globals(), {})
False
```

---

Now lets see whats happening in your case..

I've modified your script a bit and added `print(list(globals()), list(locals())); print(locals() is globals())` these two lines like below.

```
myblock = """
def iszero(x):
    return x == 0

args = [0, 1, 2]

# added these two stmts here
print(list(locals()))
print(list(globals()))
print(locals() is globals())

flts = list(filter(lambda f:(not iszero(f)), args)) #NameError
"""
```

And after executing the above string by using `exec` with `locals` as empty dict.

```
>>> exec(myblock, globals(), {})
['iszero', 'args']
['__package__', 'myblock', '__builtins__', '__spec__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__']
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 12, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'iszero' is not defined
```

It is clear that `locals` space it getting added all the attributes. so you would never gonna see `iszero` method in `globals` if you pass `locals` as `{}`.

And the reason you are getting `NameError` for the closure `list(filter(lambda f:(not iszero(f)), args))` it started lookup at `globals` instead of `locals` and your globals doesn't have the method defined.

Comment: If the `exec`ed code is put inside a plain function instead, then `globals()` and `locals()` from inside the function look the same as they do here; in particular, `iszero` is inside the function's locals, and not `globals`; but the reference to `iszero` inside the lambda works.  Why doesn't the lambda function look in the enclosing scope's locals in my example - isn't that the point of closures?